# How to fire an event only when text is entered in an input box but not removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code snippet triggers an alert event when a number is entered (or removed from) into a `9 * 9` Sudoku grid.

```
   $('table tr td input').on({"input": function () {
            var cell = $(this).val();

            if (!$.isNumeric(cell)) {
                alert("Please enter only numbers from 1 to 9");
            }

   }});
```

But how to remove the alert message when text is removed ? It has to be triggered only when number is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (!$.isNumeric(cell)) {
```

to

```
if (cell && !$.isNumeric(cell)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following.

```
$('table tr td input').on({"input": function () {
        var cell = $(this).val();

        if (cell.length > 0 && !$.isNumeric(cell)) {
            alert("Please enter only numbers from 1 to 9");
        }
}});
```